# Google Maps API Marker Clusterer Change Level Size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm trying to change level size of Google Maps API Marker Clusterer. 
For default, the marker small size (blue icon/m1): 2-9 markers, medium level size (yellow icon/m2): 10-100 markers, big level (red icon/m3) size: 101-250 markers. (correct Me if I wrong).

I want to change the value of level size smaller than default. I have found another thread with same topic but I still didn't get clearly point.

This is the Google Maps API Marker Cluster icon I meant:

[Google Maps API Marker Clusterer Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5dH.jpg)

PS: I didn't mention about how to change clusterer icon, I meant how to change value of size. Ex: How I can change the level size of marker so it will be clustered to blue (m1), yellow (m2), and red(m3)? The default size like I mentioned before, for m1 it's contain of 2-9 markers, can I change the size value to 2-5 markers only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Api v3, custom Cluster icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416089/google-maps-api-v3-custom-cluster-icon)

Comment: I didn't mention about how to change clusterer icon, I meant how to change value of size. Ex: How I can change the level size of marker so it will be clustered to blue (m1), yellow (m2), and red(m3)? The default size like I mentioned before, for m1 it's contain of 2-9 markers, can I change the size value to 2-5 markers only?

Comment: Related question: [How to hide the numbers on a cluster marker in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335396/how-to-hide-the-numbers-on-a-cluster-marker-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom `Calculator` function.  From the [source](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) (of the version referenced in Google's documentation, be sure to verify with the documentation of the version you are using, which you didn't provide).  The default `calculator` function:

```
/**
 *  The function for calculating the cluster icon image.
 *
 *  @param {Array.<google.maps.Marker>} markers The markers in the clusterer.
 *  @param {number} numStyles The number of styles available.
 *  @return {Object} A object properties: 'text' (string) and 'index' (number).
 *  @private
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.calculator_ = function(markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var count = markers.length;
  var dv = count;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
    text: count,
    index: index
  };
};
```

The function to set it (which describes its return value, the index is the index into the array of icons, the text is the text to display on the cluster):

```
/**
 * Set the calculator function.
 *
 * @param {function(Array, number)} calculator The function to set as the
 *     calculator. The function should return a object properties:
 *     'text' (string) and 'index' (number).
 *
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setCalculator = function(calculator) {
  this.calculator_ = calculator;
};
```